# How to start a new Django project using poetry?

Tags: python, django, virtualenv, python-poetry

How to start a new Django project using poetry?

With virtualenv it is simple:

```
virtualenv -p python3 env_name --no-site-packages
source env_name/bin/activate
pip install django
django-admin.py startproject demo
pip freeze > requirements.txt
```

What will be equivalent to this using Poetry?

Comment: You've posted three questions here, please focus and ask one per post.

Comment: Docs are here; https://python-poetry.org/docs/basic-usage/

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Create a new project folder and step in:

```
$ mkdir djangodemo
$ cd djangodemo
```

Create a basic `pyproject.toml` with `django` as dependency:

```
$ poetry init --no-interaction --dependency django
```

Create venv with all dependencies needed:

```
$ poetry install
```

Init your demo-project:

For Django versions after 4:

```
$ poetry run django-admin startproject djangodemo
```

For Django version less than 4:

```
$ poetry run django-admin.py startproject djangodemo
```

Comment: Why do we need to use `poetry run ...` in this case? I noticed that that works where `django-admin ...` alone does not, but I don't understand why.

Comment: The `django-admin.py` needs to be run within the virtual environment to have access to all it's dependencies. `poetry run` starts a new shell, activates the virtual environment and runs the command. Afterwards it closes the shell again.

Comment: you can also run `poetry shell` which will open shell with virtualenv and then you can run all your commands as usual.

Comment: Can I use virtualenvwrapper and run commands without `poetry shell|run`?

Comment: If you are using django 4.0, it's django-admin, not django-admin.py!

Comment: @bayman THANKS. Why would anyone change something like that..